# I want to change Template background color to Indian Flag tri colors

Tags: html, css

I am new to web developing i created a simple one page template in html which is working fine but i wanted to change background color to Indian Flag Tri-color i dont understand how to proceed i never used 2-3 colors in a single Page

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>  <title>Netzach’s</title>  
<meta charset="utf-8"> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">  

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>  
<style>  
body {      font: 400 15px/1.8 Lato, sans-serif;      color: ##ff7f00;  }  

h3, h4 {      margin: 10px 0 30px 0;      letter-spacing: 10px;            
font-size: 20px;      color: #228b22;  }

.left{text-align: left;}
      .container {      padding: 80px 120px;  }  .person {      border: 10px solid transparent;      margin-bottom: 25px;      width: 80%;      height: 80%;      opacity: 0.7;  }  .person:hover {      border-color: #228b22;  }  .carousel-inner img {      -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%);      filter: grayscale(90%); /* make all photos black and white */       width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */      margin: auto;  }  .carousel-caption h3 {      color: #ff7f00!important;  }  @media (max-width: 600px) {    .carousel-caption {      display: none; /* Hide the carousel text when the screen is less than 600 pixels wide */    }  }  .bg-1 {      background: #2d2d30;      color:   #228b22;  }  .bg-1 h3 {color: #ff7f00;}  .bg-1 p {font-style: italic;}  .list-group-item:first-child {      border-top-right-radius: 0;      border-top-left-radius: 0;  }  .list-group-item:last-child {      border-bottom-right-radius: 0;      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;  }  .thumbnail {      padding: 0 0 15px 0;      border: none;      border-radius: 0;  }  .thumbnail p {      margin-top: 15px;      color: #555;  }  .btn {      padding: 10px 20px;      background-color: #333;      color: #f1f1f1;      border-radius: 0;      transition: .2s;  }  .btn:hover, .btn:focus {      border: 1px solid #333;      background-color: #fff;      color: #000;  }  .modal-header, h4, .close {      background-color: #228b22;      color: #fff !important;      text-align: center;      font-size: 30px;  }  .modal-header, .modal-body {      padding: 40px 50px;  }  .nav-tabs li a {      color: #ff7f00;  }  #googleMap {      width: 100%;      height: 400px;      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);      filter: grayscale(100%);  }    .navbar {      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;      margin-bottom: 0;      background-color: #2d2d30;      border: 0;      font-size: 11px !important;      letter-spacing: 4px;      opacity: 0.9;  }  .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {       color: #ff7f00 !important;  }  .navbar-nav li a:hover {      color: #fff !important;  }  .navbar-nav li.active a {      color: #fff !important;      background-color: #ff7f00 !important;  }  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {      border-color: transparent;  }  .open .dropdown-toggle {      color: #fff;      background-color: #ff7f00 !important;  }  .dropdown-menu li a {      color: #000 !important;  }  .dropdown-menu li a:hover {      background-color: red !important;  }  footer {      background-color: #228b22;      color: #228b22;      padding: 32px;  }  footer a {      color: #228b22;  }  footer a:hover {      color: #777;      text-decoration: none;  }    .form-control {      border-radius: 0;  }  textarea {      resize: none;  }
    td{border-style: groove;}
      </style>  
        <!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section --> <!-- add to the <head> of your page -->   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine0/style.css" />  <!--script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/jquery.js"></script-->   <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section --></head><body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50"><nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">  <div class="container-fluid">    <div class="navbar-header">      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">        <span class="icon-bar"></span>        <span class="icon-bar"></span>        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                              </button>      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage"><img src="" alt="Logo"></img></a>    </div>    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">        <li class="active"><a href="#myPage">HOME</a></li>        <li><a href="#band">ABOUT US</a></li>        <li class="dropdown">          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#Services">SERVICES           <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
              </a>          <!--<ul class="dropdown-menu">            <li><a href="#">Electoral</a></li>            <li><a href="#">Media P.R</a></li>          <li><a href="#">Legal Consultancy</a></li>          <li><a href="#">Training and Development</a></li>            <li><a href="#">Advertisment</a></li>          </ul> -->
     <li><a href="#Assignments">ASSIGNMENTS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Career">CAREER</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>        </li>        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></li>      </ul>    </div>  </div></nav>

    <!--
        <div id="wowslider-container0"> <div class="ws_images"><ul>
            <li><img src="data0/images/slide1.jpg" alt="SLIDE" title="SLIDE" id="wows0_0"/></li>
            <li><a href="http://wowslider.com"><img src="data0/images/slide2.png" alt="http://wowslider.com/" title="SLIDE" id="wows0_1"/></a></li>
            <li><img src="data0/images/slide3.jpg" alt="slide" title="slide" id="wows0_2"/></li>
        </ul></div>
        <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
            <a href="#" title="SLIDE"><span><img src="data0/tooltips/slide1.jpg" alt="SLIDE"/>1</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="SLIDE"><span><img src="data0/tooltips/slide2.png" alt="SLIDE"/>2</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="slide"><span><img src="data0/tooltips/slide3.jpg" alt="slide"/>3</span></a>
        </div></div><div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a href="http://wowslider.com">responsive slider</a> by WOWSlider.com v8.7</div> <div class="ws_shadow"></div>   </div>   -->    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/wowslider.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/script.js"></script>    <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->  <!-- Container (The Band Section) --><div id="band" class="container text-center">  <h3>About Us</h3>    <p class="left">Who We are

    Netzach’s in Election Research is a leading public opinion polling company

    specializing in political, public affairs, public policy research and development in

    India since 2007. We are empowered by state of the art research practices, managerial

    acumen and best analysts. We are in research, media consultancy and strategic

    communications.

    We are giving out excellent analysis, which are not only significant but also

    undisputed. We make unbiased projections having estimated the outcomes having

    estimated the outcomes of every State and National election since our inception. Our

    accuracy in local body elections is unparalleled. We project and predict the political

    situation with a clear cut indication based on authentic research and survey.

    We provide accurate, non – partisan, evidence based relevant data and analysis on

    public opinions, government policies on the issues, attitudes and trends shaping

    India and across the world.

    We partner with national policy makers, government institutions, political parties,

    NGO’s, Media houses, Corporate organisations to enhance their data and set of

    information, as our research is focused on producing accurate data that compels

    decisions to power engagement, strategy for government marketing and

    communication that derives results adding value to their output.

    We help in enhancing the activities of decision makers across all the vibrant sectors

    of economy and politics.

    What we do

    Since last 10 years, Netzach’s has been helping political parties and candidates to win

    tough elections, by developing and implementing innovative research methodologies

    and research strategies designed for the candidates and their constituencies. We

    provide a winning formula with a set of actionable ideas, thereby helping them to beat

    their competitors. Owing to the dynamic nature of this wherein each constituency is

    different, our approach to each constituency is also different and unique. Our

    quantitative and qualitative research prowess has been established. We go all out to

    aggressively help our clients formulate their goals, achievements and interests in

    best possible manner. Along with providing insights achieved through our research

    data, we even help our clients implement them. Our USP is that, we can offer strategic

    and tactical recommendations based on our findings.

    Our research output takes varied final forms such as Opinion Polls, Exit Polls,

    Reports, Research Papers, Audio-Visual Programming packages for TV, Internet

    Programming and Social Media dissemination. Given our ability to work in multi-

    cultural environments and experience in establishing cross demographic service

    delivery models. We have handled media consultancy assignments across the

    country.</p>  <br>    <!-- Modal -->  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">    <div class="modal-dialog">          <!-- Modal content-->      <div class="modal-content">        <div class="modal-header">          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Tickets</h4>        </div>        <div class="modal-body">          <form role="form">            <div class="form-group">              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Tickets, $23 per person</label>              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="How many?">            </div>            <div class="form-group">              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Send To</label>              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">            </div>              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Pay                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>              </button>          </form>        </div>        <div class="modal-footer">          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel          </button>          <p>Need <a href="#">help?</a></p>        </div>      </div>    </div>  </div></div>
    <div id="Services" class="container text-center">

      <h3>Services</h3>
      <div class="row">

    <p>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <h3>Psephological Consultancy:</h3>
    We provide solutions at every level at your doorstep. Some of them are:
    <table style="border-style: dotted;" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <tr>
    <td>Political surveys</td>
    <td>Constituency profiling</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Candidate positioning</td>
    <td>Political party position</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Opinion polls</td>
    <td>Pre -Poll</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Exit Poll</td>
    <td>Tracking Poll</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Election campaign management</td>
    <td>Increase voter awareness and support</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Public opinion creation</td>
    <td>Bring the voter to booth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Campaign support </td>
    <td>Media and social media support</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 left">
    <p><h3>Market Research</h3>

    The skills required for stakeholder research are easily transferable towards addressing client requirements such as market assessment, preparation of concept notes, demand quantification, customer feedback and brand image building. The services are not limited by geography or the industry type. Given our experience in various elections and ready access to top consultants within India and abroad. We will be glad to offer you customized solutions for your market research.
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 left">
    <p> <h3>Media Consultancy</h3>
    From providing content outsourcing to training and set up of niche programming streams such as election programming to full fledged turnkey solutions tailored for print and electronic media. Netzach’s is your one stop shop for your consultancy needs. Not only have we successfully operated in diverse media environments such as News Agency, TV Channels, Newspapers, Magazines and Internet media, we have also delivered value to our clients cutting across borders. We are adept at providing localized and customized consultancy suited to the milieu in which our clients operate.
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 left"><p><h3>Socio-Economic Research</h3>
    Netzach’s is proud to have partnered with academic institutions, NGOs, Independent Researchers and various Industry bodies in production of socio-economic data and research reports. Furthering the frontiers of human well being was one of the founding motives of our organization and we are proud to have done justice to the same. We encourage individuals and bodies engaged in socio-economic research to work with us. our clients cutting across borders. We are adept at providing localized and customized consultancy suited to the milieu in which our clients operate.
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 left">
    <p>
    <h3>Qualitative Consultancy</h3>
    Ever felt the need to talk to someone who understands the local polity and culture beyond what the numbers convey? Our team of highly trained analysts and consultants who have years of experience under their belt would be glad to offer you some advice. Not only do we have access to best political analysts in the business we also have a enviable network of consultants who are ready to provide niche consultancy services to our clients.
    </p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 left"><p><h3>Public Private Partnerships</h3>
    Our experience with democratic processes and formidable skill set in determining policy direction empower us to be an active partner of the host government in public-private partnership projects. Sectors such as Education, Resource mapping, Governance Surveys, Independent Evaluation and Policy assessment are some of the streams that have witnessed active Netzach’s participation or demonstrated deploy-able capability to execute the projects satisfactorily.
    </p></div>


    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Assignments" class="container text-center">
     <h3>Assignments</h3>
    <div   class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center"><h3>Recent Assignments</h3><p></p></div>
    <br/>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center"><h3>Ongoing project</h3><p class="center">
    </p></div></div>
    <div id="Career" class="container text-center">
     <h3>Career</h3>
    <div  class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 left"><p><h3>Interns</h3>
    Netzach’s offers college and university students a snapshot of professional life that awaits them via a limited number of internships. The selection criteria for the internships are very 
    stringent and we advise the students to generate a very high quality cover letter and a CV that delineates their extra-curricular and curricular activities to better help us evaluate their merits. Email us to: netzachsrnd@outlook.com
    Please write "Internship" in the subject line of the mail.
    We offer Opportunities for professional growth and development
    Platform to express freely and multi tasking
    </p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 left"><p><h3>Competitive package</h3>
    Flexibility and learning while working experience.
    </p></div></p>
     <br>
     </div> 
    <!-- Container (Contact Section) --><div id="contact" class="container">  <h3 class="text-center">Contact</h3><div class="row">
    Please enter your details in the form below or email to netzachsrnd@outlook.com. We will contact you shortly.
      <br/>  <div class="col-md-4">      <p>Drop a Message here</p>      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>Mumbai, India</p>      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>Phone: 000000000</p>      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Email: netzachsrnd@outlook.com</p>         </div>    <div class="col-md-8">      <div class="row">        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>        </div>        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>        </div>      </div>      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea>      <br>      <div class="row">        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">          <button class="btn pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>        </div>      </div>      </div>  </div>  <br><br><br><br>  <!--Fixed Footer--> <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">            <div class="navbar-text pull-left">        <p> © 2016 Netzach`s.</p>     </div>   </div> <br><br> </footer><script>$(document).ready(function(){  // Initialize Tooltip  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();     // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {    // Prevent default anchor click behavior    event.preventDefault();    // Store hash    var hash = this.hash;    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll    // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area    $('html, body').animate({      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top    }, 900, function(){         // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)      window.location.hash = hash;    });  });})</script></body></html>
```

Comment: Is there any code that you already have and where you got problems with? Please add more details and code, so we can help.

Comment: code added i just wants to add colors in background rest working fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Rakesh. Can you edit down that code to provide just the relevant parts? Could samples should demonstrate the problem as concisely as possible.

Comment: there is no problem in the code just want to add colors in background tri-color saffron white and green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple linear gradient

```
background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #138808 33%, #ffffff 33%, #ffffff 66%, #FF9933 66% );
```

Comment: thank you sir ur code helped me and how can i include navbar n footer also in this?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Could you mark my answer as accepted? I suggest you look for some online tutorial for your next problem.

Comment: @ThomasRay is there some way I can make small twitches to this linear gradient? Let's say I want to do a merger between saffron and white and one between white and green but just for 2.5% into each of them

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution, add this to your CSS.

```css
body { 
  background-position: left top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"); 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <pre>
    This
    is
    some
    text...
    Hello
    World
  </pre>
</body>
```